# Function specifiers in .h and .c files

Tags: c++, c

Just a simple question - do i have to specify function's specifiers in a .c file if i've already specified them in a .h file?

**.h file:**

```c
inline void func(void);
```

**.c file:**

```c
/*do i have to put inline here aswell?*/ void func(void) {}
```

Comment: C or C++? The answer might be different.

Comment: Answers regarding both would be nice, at first i thought there are no differences between C and C++ when it comes to this topic.

Comment: For C the answer is no, specifier is not required at the definition (see [C11 6.7.4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4)). However... for `inline` it really doesn't make sense to have it in the header file in the first place.

Comment: The answer is the same in both C and C++: **Don't use `inline` in a header if you are defining in the source file**

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the `inline` function in the one .c file, you do not need to put the prototype in the .h file. You make the function `static inline` in the .c file.

If you are using the `inline` function in multiple .c files, then you need to put it's full definition in the .h file so it's visible to all uses.